# NestJS + Mongoose + GraphQL : "populate" not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, nestjs, mongoose-populate

thanks for the great framework!

I use mongoose with GraphQL and have the following problem:

If I want to resolve the ObjectIDs stored in the array "arguments" of a user with `populate`, in GraphQL I get the user with an empty arguments array as answer.

I suspect the error when defining the reference `ArgumentSchema` (name of the MongoDB schema) or the populate `arguments` (name of the attributes of the user). How does this work correctly?

**argument.schema**

```
export const ArgumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  argument: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

**user.schema**

```
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, required: true },
  arguments: { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], required: false, ref: 'ArgumentSchema' },
});
```

**argument.model**

```
@ObjectType()
export class ArgumentGQL {
  @Field(() => ID)
  readonly _id: string;

  @Field()
  readonly argument: string;

  @Field()
  readonly userId: string;

  @Field()
  readonly username: string;
}
```

**user.model**

```
@ObjectType()
export class UserGQL {
  @Field(() => ID)
  readonly _id: string;

  @Field()
  readonly username: string;

  @Field()
  readonly email: string;

  @Field()
  readonly age: number;

  @Field(() => [ArgumentGQL], { nullable: true })
  readonly arguments: ArgumentGQL[];
}
```

**user.service**

```
async getOne(id: string): Promise<UserGQL> {
    try {
      return await this.userModel.findById(id).populate('arguments').exec();
    } catch (e) {
      throw new BadRequestException(e);
    }
  }
```

**GraphlQL Query example**

```
query {
  getUser(id: "5dbcaf9f5ba1eb2de93a9301") {
      _id,
      username,
      email,
      age,
      arguments {
          argument,
          username
      }
  }
}
```

I think I haven't understood something fundamental yet...

I would be grateful for any help!
Cheers

Comment: I'm having the same problem do you have this project repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the problem, maybe is the way you defined `user.schema`. As It mentioned [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), have you tried this?

```js
{
 arguments: [{ type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], , ref: 'ArgumentSchema' }],
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! You saved me hours ;)

Comment: @stoniemahonie You are welcome :) By the way, I use [Typegoose](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose) and I think it's a bit cleaner.